# Freefall: Why can't Florence ask the robots for a genetic engineering facility?

Tags: freefall-webcomic

In [Freefall](http://freefall.purrsia.com/ffdex.htm) Florence is the only [Bowman's Wolf](http://en.wikifur.com/wiki/Bowman%27s_Wolf) on the planet, and the total population of Bowman's Wolves is too small to be viable anyway.

However Florence now has millions of robots in her debt, and they are very eager to help anyone they can. She also knows that Dr Bowman is on the planet. So why can't she ask the robots to build a genetic engineering facility and ask Dr Bowman to use it to make more Bowman's Wolves?

Comment: That's an interesting question, which I'm trying to figure out how to answer without it coming off as an opinion piece. First off, she's still afraid that Ecosystems Unlimited might extinct Bowman's Wolves if she pushes too hard. Two, she still has a lot of deep programming about going against humans. Three, countering point one would probably require a high rate of production and I think that goes against her instincts of natural raising of children.

Comment: I don't think Ecosystems Unlimited would allow Dr. Bowman to create any more Bowman's Wolves at this point, so the robots would have to break him out.  Seems like a very extreme step.  Even if Florence was willing to go to such extremes, it doesn't seem like the best time - the status of the robots in society still isn't fully settled IIRC, and Blunt for one would no doubt take full propaganda advantage of any unfortunate incidents.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That sounds like an answer. Post it, and if nobody comes up with anything better I'll accept it.